# why is resultant of a vector has the same direction as the position vector of another point but has different initial point?

Tags: vectors

suppose two points $A$ and $B$ have their position vectors $\vec{OA}=3\hat i +5\hat j$ and $\vec{OB}=5\hat i +4\hat j$
then $\vec{BA}=-2\hat i +\hat j$. Now $\vec{BA}$ seems to be the position vector of point $(-2,1)$ with respect to the origin. Since we are determining all these vectors with respect to the origin why does that resultant correspond to position vector of another point and both of them have the same direction even though their initial points are different?

I used to think that suppose we are assume all those vectors to be displacement. A person starting with an intention to displace from O to B then to A will start from o then stop at B at first step. Then to go to A he needs a direction at that point with respect to him the origin is at B and point A corresponds to $(-2,1)$.

could it be the reason or there any other reasoning or explanation behind this?

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/698387/8446) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4397016/21813).

Answer (score 1):

You keep referring to position, but keep in mind that geometrically, a Euclidean vector is only characterized by its *magnitude* and *direction*:

[image]

One may place a vector anywhere in the coordinate plane. Wherever placed, geometrically, vectors are added tip-to-tail:

[image]

Comment: so in this case it  obeys the exact lexical meaningof definition of vectors right? that is nothing other than **magnitude** and **direction**

Comment: @MSKB I am not sure what you mean by "in this case." A Euclidean vector is characterized by magnitude and direction.